# What is the right preposition after teach

Tags: grammar

I could not find any information which of the following is correct:

- To teach someone on a subject
- To teach someone in a subject

What seems to be correct is "to teach someone about a subject". But "about" sounds to me as if you are casually teaching something. In contrast, Teaching "in" something sounds more like an active process over several lessons. What do you think?

Any hints apprectiated.

Comment: I taught my son about the birds and the bees.

Comment: A teacher teaches a subject, but they might teach the class _about_ a particular topic within that subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, no preposition is needed.

> I taught my son arithmetic.
>
> Elementary school teachers must teach their students many subjects.

Comment: Ok thanks. But is it wrong to use for example "on": I taught my son on arithmetic.

Comment: @User878239, it sounds unnatural to me, but I can't speak for all varieties of English.

Comment: "In" is less unnatural (to me) than "on" but still seems just a bit "off".

Comment: No prep in the usual way, but in passives, 'to' often works.  E.g. I taught them English. PV one: They were taught English (by me). PV two: English was taught to them..  I can't see anything else.

Comment: @RamPillai, "to" indicates who was taught, not the subject that was taught.

Comment: One example with *in* would be a teacher talking to a parent about a student in a course. The teacher could say “Two years ago, I taught your son in arithmetic”.  Here, *arithmetic* is a shortened form of *arithmetic class*.  The usage becomes more natural as the subject of the course becomes more broad, and the teacher wishes to convey that he or she was only one of many people that conveyed knowledge to the student.